# how to use http_build_query to replicate this sending of array data

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm submitting a POST form submission using CURL, and have an array of fields. One of the fields is an array, but is submitted to the server as `foo=1&foo=2&foo=3`. If I store the values like so: `$data['foo'][] = 1; $data['foo'][] = 2; $data['foo'][] = 3`, then `http_build_query` converts it to `foo[0]=1&foo[1]=2...`.

Other than manually appending the string onto the output of the `http_build_query` for the other fields, how can I achieve this type of array-to-string conversion?